# pjsip android : dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__aeabi_memclr8

Tags: android, android-ndk, pjsip

I have build pjsip for android using Ndk r18b.
the pjsip is successfully build for following android architecture.
  1. arm64-v8a
  2. armeabi-v7a
  3. x86_64
this library is working fine in mostly devices but we are facing this issue:

> "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol
>   "__aeabi_memclr8" referenced by
>   "/data/app/com.inextrix.astppdialer-2/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so"..." in one
>   plus A0001 device. also facing issue : "com.inextrix.astppdialer
>   E/art:
>   dlopen("/data/app/com.inextrix.astppdialer-1/lib/arm64/libpjsua2.so",
>   RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "freeifaddrs"
>   referenced by
>   "/data/app/com.inextrix.astppdialer-1/lib/arm64/libpjsua2.so"..."

in oppo f1s device.

right now my pjsua2.so file is not properly load in one plus & oppo device. i want to fix this issue for every device.

please guide me which ndk version is right for build pjsip2.9.

Comment: Refer this link: https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk/issues/313 or... https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/126

Answer (score 3):

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/user/common_problems.md#cannot-locate-symbols

You're building a library for an API level above your `minSdkVersion`. You can't do that. Your NDK API level needs to match your `minSdkVersion`.